# How can I make custom python package with import of modules usable stand-alone and within another package with its own namespace?

Tags: python

I have built a minimum example with the following structure:

[image: structure]

I have a python package `package1`, which **needs to work standalone** by calling `main_function_of_package1.py`:

```
import functions.add as func_add

def main():
    c = func_add.sum(1,3)
    print(f'package1 says: {c}')
    
    return(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, I **additionaly** want to use this package in another location/repo `FOLDER_IMPORT_TEST`. In this package, there is another `main_function.py`:

```
import package1.main_function_of_package1
import functions.add as func_add

def main():
    print(f'Main package call yields: {func_add.sum(1,3)}')

    print(f'package1.main_function call yields: {package1.main_function_of_package1.main()}')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now I want the `package1` module to use its `functions` sub-package and the `main_function.py` to use its own `functions` sub-package. Of course, I could give it a different name and just add the package1.functions to the PYTHONPATH or syspath. However, I'd like to keep a clean namespace to prevent accidential use of wrong functions.

Basically I want the package1 to work just like a package that I installed via pip install, i.e. its using its own submodules and whatever without adding all its sub-packages and sub-modules to the namespace of my FOLDER_IMPORT_TEST.

You might wonder why I'm doing this: I have a post-processing repo (represented here by the `package1`). This repo and its functions (represented by the `main_function_of_package1.main()` with the sub-package and modules in `functions`) are used by different people for post-processing our data. Now, I have a new usecase, where I want to implement some automatic testing features. To do so, I need the post-processing. To not implement the same functionality twice or copy functions, I want to use the post-processing repo (`package1`) as a git submodule in my new `FOLDER_IMPORT_TEST` repo.

Comment: Why would you have to touch PYTHONPATH directly at all?